# How could a US state, party or rep. go about the process of contesting the loss of a seat in the House of Representatives? (slim census margin)

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, voting-districts, census

The title of CNN's [New York to lose House seat -- and an Electoral College vote -- after falling 89 residents short in census count](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/26/politics/new-york-census-house-seat-electoral-college-vote/index.html) sums up the situation as does Axios' [States that voted for Biden lose 3 net House seats after Census count](https://www.axios.com/census-apportionment-states-house-representatives-3ada2a93-346a-4b59-9e42-54bd500353d8.html)

> A census official said if New York had counted 89 additional people, the state would not have lost a congressional seat.

By law elected US representative can contest an individual election result and/or ask for a recount when the margin is small, **but this is different** in that the seat itself should no longer exist and there are not actual ballots to recount.

**Question:** How could a state, a party or an individual representative   contest a **slim margin** (in this case 89 souls) in a census result or ask for an audit or anything analogous to a recount?

---

related:

- [What happens to US representatives after a redistricting?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59600)
- [In the United States, can the distribution of congressional representatives be adjusted in response to dramatic population shifts?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59076)

Comment: Although I have not asked about redistricting, it might be an inevitable part of the answer so I've added it for now.

Comment: On the second question, it's the voters who decide who stays and who goes, or, more precisely, the decision is made through the usual election process.  The seat is lost when a new congress takes office, in this case in 2022.  But someone asked that recently -- in the last year or so -- which is why I'm not posting an answer now.  Also, states are redistricted every ten years regardless of whether they have lost or gained a seat.  Since question 2 is quite different from question 1 (and anyway a duplicate), it's probably better to remove it.

Comment: @phoog I've removed that part and added a few links, do you think that the one you're thinking of is there?

Comment: They could file a case in federal court, if they were prepared to spend the money on such a case.

Comment: Yes, I think the first one is the one I remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is spelled out in the [Administrative Procedure Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Procedure_Act_(United_States)). *See, e.g.*, [*National Urban League v. Ross*](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/court-cases/national-urban-league-v-ross) and [*Ohio v. Coggins*](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/court-cases/ohio-v-coggins). Basically, it amounts to a lawsuit against a federal government official in the chain of command involved in making the decision in question filed in a suitable U.S. District Court.

Comment: AP News 2022-01-15 [Let the challenges begin! Time for contesting census is here](https://apnews.com/article/coronavirus-pandemic-health-pennsylvania-race-and-ethnicity-census-2020-8391eeebf5c4b3d2d80acced5b09b9ef)

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to go about it is detailed by ohwilleke's answer.  But for the sake of amusement let's ignore that and consider the fallback:

### Petition/Pressure/Obstruct Congress

Reapportionment due to the Census, while required by the constitution, is not automatic and self-executing by default.  It requires an act of Congress to determine both how many seats the House of Representatives will have and how many seats each state gets.

As a point of fact, the House was never reapportioned as a result of the 1920 census (a nice summary of the events can be found in Chapter 2 of [this law review article from 2018](https://scholarship.law.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3756&context=wmlr)).  At that time reapportionment was a political hot potato, with rural states and areas fighting against a loss of representation as urban areas exploded in population.  This made reapportionment into a heated battle to decide how it would be done, and in particular decide how many members the House should have.  And the urban boon, combined with internal migrations induced by the effects of WWI, meant the population distribution had dramatically altered since 1910. Some areas were now wildly overrepresented and others wildly underrepresented.  Disagreements and brazen political obstruction got so bad that the House never came to an agreement.  The House apportionment was thus stuck at the what was determined by [the Apportionment Act of 1911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_Act_of_1911) for the entire decade.
Eventually they passed the [Reapportionment Act of 1929](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reapportionment_Act_of_1929), essentially in force to this day, fixing the number of seats at 435, as well as providing a default method for all future reapportionments. This allowed the House to finally be reapportioned as a result of the 1930 census.  While changes have been made, with reapportionment now following the provisions of [Title 2 (Section 2) of the USC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_2_of_the_United_States_Code), the basic thrust has remained the same: fix the size of the House and create a default method and process for future reapportionments.

But the point here being that if you don't want reapportionment to change your state's representation, then a technically valid way of doing so is to try to affect the necessary legislative acts of Congress.  A bit of a tall order for a single state, especially with a default process in effect, but nevertheless technically valid.

You could try to get them to pick a different method for reapportionment; the current method is the ["method of equal proportions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_apportionment#The_method_of_equal_proportions), intended to minimize the disparity in the populations of districts across the US.  In a case like the present one with New  York, a different method may change the end result so that New York does not lose a representative (though some other state might; New York's retained rep need not be removed from a state that otherwise stood to gain one).

Or you could even try to get them to increase the size of the House of Representatives. The Constitution places a maximum value on this of one representative per 30,000 people, which is currently in the neighborhood of 10,000 I think, so there's plenty of room to work in, constitutionally speaking.  The reapportionments of 1911 and earlier had typically been done in such a way as to prevent any state from losing representatives, in fact.  This could let a particular state have no net change in its total representatives.  It's proportion of representatives in the House would still go down, but it would technically keep the same number of seats.

If you can convince Congress to repeal the current default methods, or have SCOTUS declare it unconstitutional (some have advanced such an argument, but to my knowledge none have advanced it meaningfully through the courts before), then you'd be back to the situation where each reapportionment needs a new act of Congress.  If the reapportionment is a partisan issue, a single state's Representatives or Senators could fairly easily take the process hostage to try to either block such legislation entirely (recreating the 1920-1929 lack of reapportionment), or win concessions on the method that manages to favor them. A presidential veto of the apportionment law would also then be on the table, providing Congress wouldn't easily override it (if you failed to get a majority of a chamber to block it, you may still have gotten better than a third on your side).

The issue with any of these ideas, especially in the current context, is that, even devoid of the currently existing default process for reapportionment, the law detailing how reapportionment shall be done was typically enacted before the Census was carried out.  In this case, it won't be clear to anyone which states stand to gain/lose/stay-the-same from any given method once the Census data comes in.  Of course I'm also intentionally ignoring the practical, political consequences of any of the above acts.  There's also the question of whether the courts could step in and dictate or otherwise somehow force a reapportionment, which was (perhaps oddly) never resolved by the 1920 non-appportionment. But this was intended as an amusing hypothetical and technicality, rather than a practical and realistic method.

Comment: The size of the House is capped at 1/30,000 of the country's population.  For the apportionment based on the 2021 census, which counted 331,449,281 people, that's a maximum size of 11,048 representatives.

Comment: I like this answer, but I think this question would also need a different answer addressing the "US Census Bureau by default deals with this sort of thing" portion more explicitly.

Comment: Doesn't the Reapportionment Act of 1929 remove the requirement for a specific reapportionment bill every ten years, so that it's not a matter of preventing the passage of a bill for reapportionment, but rather the passing of a specific bill to override or alter the terms of reapportionment?

Comment: Mostly wrong. "The US Census Bureau by default deals with this sort of thing." The issue is error in conducting the census that could be revealed by audit or contest (which is plausible when a small number of marginal count errors are at stake), not the fact that reapportionment is conducted. Also reapportionment pursuant to the Census is mandatory under the constitution and can't be waived by statute.

Comment: @ohwilleke It can't be waved by statute, but it's not self-executing and can only be given effect by statute. And 1920-1929 gives us an explicit case where such a statute failed to materialize and reapportionment never happened.  I'm doubtful modern courts would try to force Congress to pass suitable reapportionment legislation.  They'd have to declare the nitty gritty, like which apportionment method to use and what principles of fairness take priority over which during edge cases, and how to deal with any reapportionment paradoxes that might arise, etc. are within the purview of the courts.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy " I'm doubtful modern courts would try to force Congress to pass suitable reapportionment legislation." I have absolutely no doubt that a modern court would issue an order compelling that this be done.

Comment: @ohwilleke Interesting.  Why's that?

Comment: @ohwilleke the checks and balances (and legislative independence) would generally mean a court couldn't order the legislature (US Congress) to pass a new apportionment act; the Supreme Court's authority would be limited to ruling on aspects of apportionment law in effect and ruling on their constitutionality, which might result in Congress passing a modified law to get around the constitutional issues

Comment: @eques The most likely remedy would to order apportionment be done in a manner provided by court order. This is often done in state redistricting cases if the legislature fails to remedy an illegal map.

Comment: @ohwilleke Redistricting is different from reapportionment, for one.  And I think there's a big difference here between state and federal.  The state is also subject to its own constitutional requirements and courts, and can be regulated by federal law and federal constitution as appropriate, granting many more sources of jurisdiction and authority for a court to mandate/dictate redistricting.  But only federal courts could conceivably mandate/dictate reapportionment, which is just setting the size and allocation of the House, and I don't know what authority there is to force that.

Comment: What precedent is there for a federal court to say "Congress must pass a law to this effect, which the President must sign into law, or else we'll do it all ourselves"?

Comment: @ohwilleke again that's not possible because the Court would be restricted to ruling  that a particular reapportionment law is somehow in conflict with the constitution, but couldn't on its own order any particular reapportionment to be used

Comment: @eques You are incorrect. Federal courts can, and routinely do, enter just such orders.

Comment: @ohwilleke please provide an example where a Federal court ordered the US Congress to do such a thing. Federal court on a state? Sure. There's some area where that could be possible.

Comment: @eques Congress hasn't violated this particular mandate. The remedy, and similar ones, are common in public law legislation at both the state and federal level. In general, when a legislative body fails to perform a non-discretionary duty, a court may fashion a remedy that fulfills the duty in a reasonable manner.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'd been having trouble finding any court precedent on the matter, as it would seem no cases of any substance were brought on the non-apportionment of the 1920's.  But I finally found [Department of Commerce v. Montana (1992)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/503/442/), which lends some support to your position, as it holds that the choice of apportionment method is not a "political question" and so remains within the scope of judicial review.  I remain concerned that your proposal is a violation of separation of powers, but I at least concede you've got the high ground.

Comment: @ohwilleke a reapportionment law may be subject to judicial review as the above comment suggests based upon a 1992 ruling, but that's not the same as asserting SCOTUS can order a particular reapportionment. The comparison to redistricting is irrelevant because those cases are a court ordering a correction to a district map that is illegal in regards some law, likely Federal law. The only parallel for reapportionment would be if the updated allotment violated the law as enacted because there is no law above the constitution to define reapportionment (A Fed concern)